# why to use self hosting in WCF?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, self-hosting

I have used WCF for hosting in IIS with svc file. I am pretty much clear on that part but just out of curiosity, why do we need WCF self hosting? I have seen 100s examples online HOW TO self host, so I know how it is done. My question is why? Why are we doing it. If anyone has used self hosting in projects can help me to understand it.

Comment: *My question is why? Why are we doing it.* - because generic hosting or "self-hosting" is actually the default hosting option for WCF. Why? It doesn't require IIS. Simple.

Comment: With self hosting can we connect to the service with the end points from outside the hosting machine?

Comment: Well, if you couldn't do that then self-host would be completely pointless...

Comment: So in what scenarios do we use self hosting? Because the whole purpose of a service is to connect 2 nodes [computers].

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. You *can* use a self-hosted service to communicate with other nodes. I don't understand why you would think otherwise because you are right, it would have no purpose.

Comment: I think I read your comment wrong. if it's possible to connect to our WCF service from other machines, self hosting gives us a way to host without IIS. I think it's clear for me. Thanks.

Comment: No problem!!!!!!!